# set color of conky

Tags: colors, conky, fontconfig

I want to set the color of a line to a specific shade of yellow (but not just yellow).

I set it like this:

```
  ${font LCDMono:bold:size=20}${color yellow}Uptime:$color $uptime
```

Where all the line has a font size of 20, and only the word "Uptime" will be yellow. The thing is that I don't want it in that kind of yellow, I want it in a more pale yellow (#FCD862 in hexa).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conky [lets you](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html) define your own color:

> colorN : Predefine a color for use inside TEXT segments. Substitute N by a digit between 0 and 9, inclusively. When specifying the color value in hex, omit the leading hash (#).

So, add this line before the `TEXT` part of `conkyrc`:

```
color1 FCD862
```

Then, use `$color1` instead of `$color`:

```
${font LCDMono:bold:size=20}${color1}Uptime:$color $uptime
```